# How to fix Bad Pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am a beginner in C and as I was trying to make a simple snake game, I stumbled upon the problem of value change in pointers when used in another function. I used pointers in order to grow my snake and I used 3 of them. Granted this might be a really noobish algorithm for a snake game but I feel like I am almost there but I cannot figure out what went wrong. I have used 3 pointes for the snake itself, the x coordinate of each part of the snake and also the y. I might as well just post a part of my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<conio.h>

printer(int *forgoodness,int *y,char *lang,int tx,int ty, int *x)
{
int h=*forgoodness-1,g=0;
```

The value changes in here, somehow the x copies 6 values of the y.

```
 /* for(;g<15;g++)
{
    printf("%i",x[g]);
}*/
for(;h>=0;h--)
{
    gotoxy(x[h],y[h]);
    printf("%c",lang[h]);
}
    gotoxy(tx,ty);
    printf(" ");
}  


main()
{
int transferx=1,x=1,transfery=1,ch,game=0,dir;
int *transx, *transy, *numel;
int tempsx,g=0,tempsy,forex,j=0,*totalel;
char *snake;
int *snakey, *snakex;
```

If I explicitly assign values it works well but I cannot grow my snake using this:

```
//int snakex[15]={26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40};
//int snakey[15]={13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13};
clrscr();
*totalel=0;
*numel=14;
forex=26;
snake= "***************";
```

This is what I did, and I checked the values before the function printer runs and the values are fine.

```
for(;j<15;j++)
{
    snakey[j]=13;
    snakex[j]=forex;
    *totalel=j;
    forex++;
}


printer(numel,snakey,snake,transferx,transfery,snakex);
```

I hope that you can help me on this. Cheers.

Comment: Is j = 0 before you init you array? Can you give us your whole code?

Comment: Hi, that is basically the code, the rest is just about moving using the arrow keys. And yes j=0 is the first index of my array.

Comment: You need to initialize `j` at the start of your `for` loop, as in `for(j = 0; j < 15; j++)` (which is what @LidongGuo was trying to tell you).

Comment: It is still the same. :(

Comment: Are you malloc'ing memory for the snake pointers `snakex` and `snakey`? It is unclear how you attempt to grow the snake. As a suggestion, maybe you should just make an array as lengthy as the snake could be, and set to -1 the elements where it has not grown yet.

Comment: Where is the code that initializes `snakex`, `snakey`, `numel`, `transx`, `transy`?

Comment: user2553780 problem solved! I just used malloc. Thank you so much for that idea. I have to read about how it solved my problem now. And no I cannot used a specific size of array for the reason that it is going to waste memory since I do not really know how many I'm going to need. Cheers.

Comment: @user2624491 No problem! Glad to help. But it will never be as lengthy to eat all your memory ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe attempt to rewrite a bit of your code... ideally using less pointers.  Based on the code I see, it looks as if you're feeding values into random pointers.  That's pretty dangerous.

For instance, doing these two lines in a row is bad:

```
int *num;
*num = 9;
```

The reason is because `num` is just a pointer to memory... and it isn't currently pointing to anything valid yet.  The number 9 is attempting to be stored in some random location.  You need to allocate some memory for `num` to point to, or point it to the address of another variable (a non-pointer integer).  I think maybe you're not quite grasping the concepts of pointers just yet.  But don't worry, it takes a little time.

You should be able to write your game without using any pointers at all, and maybe just use a fixed array for now like someone else had mentioned.  Then do a bit more reading up on how pointers work and take another stab at it.  I'm sure you'll get it!

But for now, try to revisit the problem with a new set of data and come back to us with what you've done so we can try to help out further.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Cool that you are working with pointers!  But as you can see, they can be a little tricky.  You have to remember that pointers are like the address of a mailbox; they can tell where something is, but they cannot (in of themselves) HOLD ANYTHING.  The can just point to something that does.  So every pointer you declare has to point to a real thing (like an int or an array element or an array) before it can be used or assigned to.  Otherwise to are shoving values into random memory areas which causes crashes.  This seems to be the main problem you are having.

```
int *ptr;
int value; 
ptr = &value;
*ptr = 10;
// value now is 10
```